# Does shield recharge rate scale with warframe's maximum shield?

Tags: warframe

Say you have 100 shield capacity and you apply the mod that improves your shield recharge rate (fast deflection) making it recharge your shield completely in 2 seconds.

Now say you have 700 shield capacity with the same amout of shield recharge rate, will it still recharge 700 in 2 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, instead of decreasing the time to fully restore, it increases how much you regenerate per second. So, if you increase the amount of your shields, it will take longer than what you figured out on the first test.

Long story short: No, it will not take 2 seconds.